# How do I get Media Player to *play* using C#?

Tags: c#, com, media-player

I'm writing an app to control an existing instance of WMP using C#.

Currently my code goes something like this:

```
private const int WM_COMMAND = 0x111;
private const int WMP9_PLAY = 0x4978;
SendMessage(WMP.MainWindowHandle, WM_COMMAND, WMP9_PLAY, 0);
```

This works fine for *pausing* media player, but if media player is paused or stopped, it skips to the next track. The command is called play, but I could have the wrong value for it. Does anyone either have a better value for WMP9_PLAY, or a better way to make WMP play?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562851(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Oh I should clarify that I'm trying to control an existing instance of WMP.exe rather than embed it in my application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using Spy++ (from the answer above) I was able to find another set of SendMessage parameters that is sent when you press the play/pause on a windows keyboard that does the job:

```
SendMessage(WMP.MainWindowHandle, 0xC02B, 0x0000000C, 0x000E0000);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the sample code here: [Interoperating with Windows Media Player using P/Invoke and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/wmp_pinvoke.aspx)